# Generating class comments in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

hi there is a way in VScode to auto generate class comments?

Like this one:

```
 /**
 * CSCI 1110 - Assignment 1
 * @author:
 * @date: 17/05/2020
 * @description: This program implements a 2-player game of Battleship
 */
```

thanks for everyone

Comment: Take a look at this VS code extension, it might do the trick: [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cschlosser.doxdocgen